# CommonAnnotations not working for AlertManager

Tags: kubernetes, slack, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to setup Alertmanager via Prometheus. I have already written my alert-rules and alertmanager.yaml file. I'm able to send alerts to slack via alertmanager.

Problem

I'm not able to beautify my alerts. I want to send description, alert name, summary with my alert.

I have tried using CommonAnnotations in order to send description, name, and summary of my alert. But unfortunately it's only working for 'DeadMansSwitch'. For all other alerts, I'm not able to see anything on slack channel.

```
#PrometheusRules

- alert: esWorkerACKSPM
        annotations:
          description: Buzzsaw esworkers acknowledgment per minute.
          summary: Prometheus' alert notification :- Buzzsaw average esworker acknowledgment per minute is lower than 10.
        expr: avg(bz_ackspm{broker=~"ldbb-.*", group="esworkers"}) < 10
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: urgent
```

```
#alertmanager.yaml

global:
templates:
- 'https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/template/default.tmpl'
route:
  group_by: ['severity']
  group_wait: 3s
  group_interval: 5s
  repeat_interval: 20s
  receiver: mail-receiver
  routes:
  - match:
      severity: urgent
    receiver: critical-mail-receiver
    routes:
receivers:
- name: 'mail-receiver'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXX/XXXXX1/e7AXXXXXXopzmHNTJmL
    channel: '#alertmanager-testing'
    text: '{{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}'
- name: 'critical-mail-receiver'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0XXXXCL/XXX6G4/VUVKZ8CnXXXXXXXzZguoXq
    channel: '#place'
    text: '{{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }} '
```

Expected Result :- Summary of the alert on the slack channel.

Actual Results :- Only able to see the summary of DeadMansSwitch (alert) on slack. For other alerts it's just showing

```
[FIRING:2] urgent (monitoring/kube-prometheus-prometheus-prometheus)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually desired behaviour. You specified grouping and the message you posted as an example is a grouped message (`[FIRING:2]` means two of the same rules matched). Therefore the additional info fields (in you case text, but also footer et al) is omitted, since there is no (easy) way to programmatically judge which of the grouped alerts should be displayed.

Which one to display? The first one or all of them (adding verbosity and lots of texts/confusion especially if more then 2 alerts are grouped)?

**So if you want to have the additional text displayed always, removing the grouping config would be the way to go.**